# Hector_slam transform issues

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, xv-11, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everybody,

I have been working at this for sometime now and i have run out of ideas.  I don't know if maybe I'm just not understanding something correctly or what.  Here is what I am trying to do:  I have an XV-11 neato lidar that I am trying to use to build a map using hector_slam. The issue is i receive the following message every time i run hector_slam:

`No transform between frames /map and /base_link available after 20.002274 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.`

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://meetjanez.splet.arnes.si/2015/08/22/neato-xv-11-to-ros-slam/) and have it setup exactly as the tutorial says.  My tf frames look exactly like [this](https://github.com/JanezCim/Neato-XV-11-Hector-SLAM/blob/master/frames.pdf).

My hector_mapping mapping_default.launch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="/scanmatcher_frame"/>
<arg name="base_frame" default="base_link"/>
<arg name="odom_frame" default="base_link"/>
<arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
<arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
<arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
<arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>

<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">

<!-- Frame names -->
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />

<!-- Tf use -->
<param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
<param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>

<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
<param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="map_pub_period" value="1.0" />
<param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />

<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.9" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />

<!-- Advertising config --> 
<param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>

<param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
<param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>

<!-- Debug parameters -->
<!--
  <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
  <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
  <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
-->
<param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
```

-->

My neato.launch file in hector_slam_launch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

  <!-- Starts the laser scan node capture thingy -->

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_frame" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /odom /base_link 10"/>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>


  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>

  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch"/> 

  <!-- <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d rviz_cfg.rviz"/> -->
  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch"/>
</launch>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237678/hector_slam-transform-issues/) by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-22**:
When I used that same tutorial with the neato I got the same message while building maps. But the maps came out just fine. Are you sure the map isn't being built? That message alone isn't enough to convince me.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-22**:
I think the 3rd arg in the default hector launch file
<arg name="odom_frame" default="base_link"/>
may be an issue involved in the failure to get the TF but I never followed it up because the mapping works fine with that message being displayed

**Comment by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on 2016-06-22**:
It does start mapping and everything runs, however, the location of the lidar jumps around and doesn't match the scans properly. The reason I think it is a transform error is because when I look at the laser scan in rviz, with map as the fixed frame, it is all over the place...

**Comment by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on 2016-06-22**:
But when the fixed frame is laser the scan looks perfect.  So I know it's not a hardware issue.  And all I can think of is the transform between the map and laser isn't working properly so hector-slam doesn't really know what to do.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-22**:
To get it work for me I had to limit the rotation speed. It is very sensitive to rotation so try it at 10% your current max rotation speed and see if that fixes it. It is also sensitive to linear speed, but not nearly as much.

**Comment by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) on 2016-06-22**:
You are a life saver.  I had it set to the lowest speed 200 rpms but as i increased the speed it actually worked a lot better so at max speed, 300 rpms, it is actually creating a map and i can move it pretty vigorously in x,y,z and it keeps the map.  Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per the comment from billy the speed of the lidar greatly impacts the SLAM.  The solution to my issue was to just increase the speed of the lidar.

Note: I do not have enough points to accept my own answer but this was my solution

---

Originally posted by [23tg94](https://answers.ros.org/users/25037/23tg94/) with karma: 18 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-22**:
Angle change per lidar update is the key metric. You want to limit the angle change of robot per lidar update. Increasing to lidar update rate by 50% as you did has the same effect as slowing robot rotation by 33%. Glad it worked out, even though you solved it differently than I suggested.

**Comment by [jcc@DU](https://answers.ros.org/users/40090/jcc@du/) on 2019-05-14**:
I am having the same problem! I have an rplidar a1, does any of you know how change the speed and the angle change as well? Thank you